# Java: HTTP PUT with HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-put

How do you do do an HTTP PUT? The class I'm using seems to think it is doing a PUT but the endpoint is treating it as if I did a GET. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
URL url = new URL("https://...");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

writer.write(xmlString);
writer.close();

System.out.println(conn.getRequestMethod());
String response = readInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
System.out.println(response);
```

Which is printing:

```
PUT
<same content as doing a GET>
```

I'd rather not include another library if this one could work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's one easy way to find out: run [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) and see what's *actually* happening on the network. I've found that to be the most reliable way of diagnosing this sort of issue - your client could have bugs, the library could have bugs, the server could have bugs, but Wireshark will show you what's really happening.

EDIT: Okay, for HTTPS it's a little trickier. You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com) if you're running on Windows, which is a proxy - it can cope with HTTPS if you can persuade your client code to accept its certificate, but that's a little more intrusive... putting a proxy in the way clearly changes what the traffic looks like.

It would be better if you could talk to a debug version of the server over HTTP instead. Is that feasible in your case, or is the server completely outside your control?

Comment: All my traffic is https to the remote server... and wireshark can't see much inside of there. Hitting it with curl vs from java DOES look different, but what should I be looking for?

Comment: Good idea. I contacted them and got a HTTP server for testing. I found my problem was the lack of a Content-Type header being rejected by their server. Thanks so much.