# How to upload a file to a site using minimal main memory

Tags: java, file-upload, ram

I want to upload a files content with a string prefixed and affixed with the file content directly to a site.
The tricky part here is i want to use minimal RAM or main memory.

Comment: What protocols / APIs are available for you to upload with?  Which one are you planning to use?  Binary content or text content?

Comment: Protocol - HTTP
Conet-type=text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Java: HTTP PUT with HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099576/java-http-put-with-httpurlconnection) or [Upload a file using HTTP put in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386832/upload-a-file-using-http-put-in-java) .  Basically, just use a `HttpURLConnection` with the 'PUT' or 'POST' method as appropriate.  Obtain the OutputStream using `.getOutputStream()`.  With this, you can write whatever you want to the server, in an efficient, streaming fashion.  Write your header/prefix, then use a buffer of the appropriate size to copy over your file contents, then write your footer/suffix, then finally close the stream.